# What's the issue in converting date from one format to another in following function code?

Tags: php, date, date-format, date-conversion

I tried following code to convert date from `mm-dd-yy` format to `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

```
function format_date_yyyy_mm_dd($date_val){ 
      if(!empty($date_val)) {
        $newDate = date("m-d-Y", strtotime($date_val));

        return $newDate;        
      } else 
        return false;            
    }
```

Suppose, the argument passed($date_val) contains the value `4-26-1991` after executing the function I'm getting the return value as `01-01-1970` instead of the desired value `1991-04-26`. How to resolve this issue? Can someone please help me? 
In addition if you provide me the function to reverse the above procees of date conversion it will be really very helpful to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This code does not do what you say it does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`DateTime`](https://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class for stuff like this. Since you have a given format (`n-j-Y`), you can pass it into the [`createFromFormat()`](https://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) method:

```
function format_date_yyyy_mm_dd($date_val) {
    $date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('n-j-Y', $date_val);
    return $date->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

For the reverse function, the normal constructor will suffice as it will be able to read the standard ISO8601 format (YYYY-MM-DD):

```
function format_date_mm_dd_yy($date_val) {
    $date = new \DateTime($date_val);
    return $date->format('n-j-Y');
}
```

Comment: yeah, it's working for me. Can you please add a function for vice versa date conversion too?

Comment: The second function should be inverse of the first function

Comment: I would recommend also using DateTimeZone parameter.

Comment: @bansi That depends whether you are (1) setting the server time zone correctly via `date_default_timezone_set` and (2) manipulating dates/times of different time zones.

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 I agree, `date_default_timezone_set` is what a lot of people miss. So just a caution.

Answer (score 2):

This function uses [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](https://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) since MM-DD-YY is ambiguous and can result in incorrect dates.

```
function format_date_yyyy_mm_dd($date_val){ 
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('n-j-y', $date_val);
    return $date->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

This function returns dates in YYYY-MM-DD format to MM-DD-YY format. Since YYYY-MM-DD is a [recognized date format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php) we don't need `DateTime::createFromFormat()` to parse our date for us:

```
function format_date_mm_dd_yy($date_val){ 
    $date = new DateTime($date_val);
    return $date->format('n-j-y');
}
```

Comment: I would recommend also using `DateTimeZone` parameter.